# Exclude Android studio from needing root permissions

Tags: fedora, permissions, sudo

I had to install Android studio in `/opt` fedora 25. I don't want to run it using sudo for various reasons. Right now I'm not setting a root password because of that.

I'm not sure if I should change `/opt` permissions to `755` or if there's a better option.

I see the following if I try make my account password protected and run Android studio without `sudo`

```
./studio.sh 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@6d5380c2 for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/opt/android-studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Trying /home/user/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/tmp/jna4343912368523517735.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /home/user/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/tmp/jna4343912368523517735.tmp
[  47553]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File /home/user/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
[  47830]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - File /home/user/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you need a `sudo` to run it? What happens if you run it without sudo?

Comment: There is nothing like "protection by `sudo`". What errors do you see?

Comment: @Jakuje please check my edit

Comment: Did you try to click Next and "select an existing SDK"?

Comment: @Jakuje sure but it won't find it, in fact the first time I installed it, I didn't know that it was an issue, even the sdk manager won't work properly. I'm thinking of `755` permissions changing permissions isn't the best idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `sudo chown -R user:user folder` on `/opt/android-studio` and on `/root/Android/Sdk` and on my project folder which I generated using android studio with root privileges.

Plus I moved  `/root/Android/Sdk` to `~/Android/Sdk` because android studio IDE cannot see the SDK if it's located in `/root`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Lynob

Based on your suggestion and on Google recommendation on a clean reinstall, I created prior installing via Google's PPA on ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/android-studio/Android
sudo mkdir /opt/android-studio/.config/Google
sudo mkdir /opt/android-studio/.local/share/Google

ln -s /opt/android-studio/Android ~/Android
ln -s /opt/android-studio/.configure/Google ~/.config/Google
ln -s /opt/android-studio/.local/share/Google ~/.local/share/Google

sudo ln -s /opt/android-studio/Android /root/Android
sudo ln -s /opt/android-studio/.configure/Google /root/.config/Google
sudo ln -s /opt/android-studio/.local/share/Google /root/.local/share/Google
```

After install

```
sudo chown -R user:user /opt/android-studio
```